# Scheduling using systemd on Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh, cron, systemd, raspberrypi, schedule

We have a Raspberry Pi, running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, which is used to run several regularly scheduled jobs. The jobs consist of Python scripts, and are run using systemd timers and services. This worked fine for months, until a few days ago. It seems now that the jobs don't run at all when they're supposed to, until I log in via SSH, and then all the jobs run at once. The `journalctl` output confirms this, with no journal entries since I last logged in. Any idea what might be causing this?

The Pi is accessed only via SSH, is connected to the network via a wired connection, and has unattended updates enabled.

Thanks!

Comment: If these are `systemd --user` scripts, you probably need to enable lingering.  As that user give the command `loginctl enable-linger` once and for all.

Comment: @meuh Oh I hadn't seen that setting before, systemd is so complicated and I'm still getting my head around it. They are indeed `--user` scripts, I enabled lingering, and it seems to have worked. Thanks!